# Progress Bar (marquee) disappears while code is running

Tags: c#

I have a simple form with a button and a progress bar. User clicks the button to begin processing and the progress bar animates while the code runs. In this case, it's just a for loop. But the problem is that the progress bar only appears for a fraction of a second then disappears.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { Thread.Sleep(1000); } // sleep 3 times for 1 second

}
```

I assume this happens because the frame is redrawn after the code continues? So I tried running the for loop on another thread but it didn't seem to matter.

How can I get the bar to animate while the loop runs?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply workaround this by including a call to Application.DoEvents() on each iteration of your loop.

But this is not the best way to achieve this.

The recommended way is processing your loop inside another thread, like a BackgroundWorker, keeping your progressbar animating on the mainthread.

You can get some explanation here: [Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx)

Comment: I say promote BackgroundWorker more. That really is the best way to go

Comment: @gunr2171 The best way would be to leverage the `async` keyword. But yes, a `BackgroundWorker` is far better than a call to `DoEvents`.

Comment: @DanielMann, `DoEvent` as I have seen doesn't do anything. And I say `BackgroundWorker` because the framework for passing objects between the threads is already there, along with (the most important part) sending status messages about your progress changes.